# Curve meshes not displaying in layout tab

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, screw-modifier

I can only see curve mesh in other tabs but it is not showing up under layout. Have everything unhidden even my reference image has disappeared,

[image]

Model has over 15,000,000 tris so am curious if its not showing to save space but I need to edit the curve while being able to view it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up/67506#67506)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in *Local* view, it means you have selected some object(s) and pressed <kbd>/</kbd> which allows to isolate the selected object(s), press <kbd>/</kbd> again to exit.

[image]

Comment: All fixed thank you!